# Prove if $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\to t$ and $t_n\geq 0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $t\geq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I've been working on some sequence practice problems in Steven Lay's *Introduction to Analysis With an Introduction to Proof* for my introductory real analysis course, as we are starting our unit on sequences next week. I encountered this problem yesterday and wasn't sure how to start it. Any hints would be welcome- thanks.

> Prove if $\{t_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\to t$ and $t_n\geq 0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, then $t\geq 0$.

Comment: *Hint:* $[0,\infty)$ is a closed set, as such it contains all of its limit points.

Comment: Values of sequence get arbitrarily close to its limit. Hence if $t < 0$ then sequence would start assuming negative values which contradicts that $t_{n} \geq 0$ for all $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$t<0\Rightarrow t\in (-\infty,0)\Rightarrow \exists \delta>0\ni (t-\delta,t+\delta)\subseteq (-\infty,0)\Rightarrow (t-\delta,t+\delta)\cap\{t_n:t_n\ge 0\forall n\in\mathbb{N}\}=\emptyset$

which means $t$ is  not  limit point of your sequence!

Comment: Just want to make sure I understand- if a sequence converges to a value, that value must be a limit point of the sequence. By showing that there are no limit points of the sequence in $(-\infty,0)$, that means that the sequence can never converge if $t\in (-\infty,0)$. Is that correct?

Comment: If a sequence converges to some limit then the limit is UNIQUE! as $\mathbb{R}$ is Hausdorf, and yes limit must be a limit point of the sequence.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your help.

Comment: you are most welcome